# Jmeter performance and load testing

Tags: jmeter

I need to load multiple files in JMeter using an HTTP requests. Can we use a single HTTP request. Files are in JSON format. Is it possible to do with a single HTTP request.

or I need to do multiple HTTP requests. I have 10,000 files for ingestion and I need to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

Both options are possible

1. Single request, multiple files - you will have to do some scripting using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) language, example code:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
   import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.TrueFileFilter
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPFileArg     

   def files = FileUtils.listFiles(new File("/path/to/folder/with/your/json/files"), TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE)

   def arguments = []

   files.eachWithIndex { file, index ->
       arguments.add(new HTTPFileArg(file.getAbsolutePath(), "your_parameter_name", "application/json"))
   }
   ```
2. Multiple requests, one file per request - the easiest option is going for [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter) plugin

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add files in files upload as

[Image of File Upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5swxN.png)

Which path should I add ....
def files = FileUtils.listFiles(new File("C:\Users\surisi\Documents\Jmeter\JSON_INPUTS\FULL"), TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE)

Answer (score -1):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
```

import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.TrueFileFilter
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPFileArg

def files = FileUtils.listFiles(new File("C:\Users\surisi\source\repos\Product\src\AzureFunctions\Common.Test.Data\Articles\Full\7635.json"), TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE)

def arguments = []

files.eachWithIndex { file, index ->
arguments.add(new HTTPFileArg(file.getAbsolutePath(), "Content-Type", "application/json"))